# Access to a React native view from native side

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I would like to create and manage a view from React native (React component with a  child) and reuse it as a sub view in a UIViewController created in Objective C.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed possible, but maybe not the way you were thinking about it.

If you look at the [`AppDelegate`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/be09cccb1f2153f84da85214b31cd4cdb4e783ec/local-cli/generator-ios/templates/app/AppDelegate.m#L46-L56) code of a React Native app, you can see a `RCTRootView` - which is just a regular `UIView` subclass - set as the view of the root view controller. Then that view takes the whole screen.

You can use the same technique and put your own `RCTRooView` as a subview of your own `UIViewController` and set its size using auto layout or whatever method you prefer.
You just have to tell that `RCTRootView` to load your module which renders your custom React Native component.

Please note that you shouldn't try to mess with the views inside a `RCTRootView` and move them to another place in your own hierarchy outside of that `RCTRootView`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I ended up finding a workaround. I create two differents RCTRootView, each targeting a different JS module.

My React native JS code:
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppMain', () => MyAppMainModule);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppSecond', () => MyAppSecondModule);

Thanks for your help :)